# protocols & viewControllers, passing info using protocols on the same action Func Swift 3 & 4

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols

I have this code to pass info between viewControllers using protocols, I have my models and with the first protocol work perfectly but the second one I have some issues, the data pass nil, or do nothing, already use tabBarController & UINavigationBar... the protocols... I create one in my ViewController(RecordViewController) and have the button & action and one protocol, this is:

```
 protocol RecordViewProtocol {

func newTrackInstrument(item: SampleCarouselsRecord)
func newInstrumentTrackCell(item: SampleTrackCellRecord)

  }

  extension RecordViewController: RecordViewProtocol {

func newTrackInstrument(item: SampleCarouselsRecord) {
    self.sampleCarouselItemsRecord.append(item)

    let indexOnPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.sampleCarouselItemsRecord.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.instrumentCarousel.insertItems(at: [indexOnPath as IndexPath])
}

func newInstrumentTrackCell(item: SampleTrackCellRecord) {
    self.sampleTrackRecord.append(item)

    let indexOnPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.sampleTrackRecord.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.trackInstrument.insertItems(at: [indexOnPath as IndexPath])
   }
}
```

the other protocol, on another ViewController(MixerViewController):...

```
  protocol MixerViewProtocol {
func newCarouselItem(item: SampleCarouselMixer)
```

}

```
  extension MixerViewController: MixerViewProtocol {
    func newCarouselItem(item: SampleCarouselMixer) {
    self.sampleCarouselMixer.append(item)

    let indexOnPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.sampleCarouselMixer.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.mixerCarouselInstrument.insertItems(at: [indexOnPath as IndexPath])
}
```

}

so, when wanna go the view and put the info to my models.. I put this code in the action Button to go into the view where is the function to put the info models:

```
   @objc func goToAddView() {

    let addTrackViewController = AddNewTrackView()

    let addTrackView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addTrackViewController)
    addTrackViewController.recordViewControllerProtocol = self as RecordViewProtocol

    present(addTrackView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and work good with the first protocol.. but with to the other protocol nothing.. I don't know why or I don't know wath I have to do... look, I have the delegate protocols inside on the AddNweTrackView:

```
  var recordViewControllerProtocol: RecordViewProtocol?
  var delegateMixerView: MixerViewProtocol?  <- this is I think, put into the action button like the firstone:
```

here on the same action where the first protocol already is

```
  @objc func goToAddView() {

let addTrackViewController = AddNewTrackView()

let addTrackView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addTrackViewController)
addTrackViewController.recordViewControllerProtocol = self as RecordViewProtocol

  addTrackViewController.delegateMixerView = MixerViewController.self as? MixerViewProtocol

present(addTrackView, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

but return nil... and I try with diferents forms.. I try put this:

```
  let mixerViewController = MixerViewController()

  addTrackViewController.delegateMixerView = mixerViewController as? MixerViewProtocol
```

and try with this but the error Is obvious:

```
  addTrackViewController.delegateMixerView = self as MixerProtocol
```

and the same... I think, here at this point, it's where Im failing .. someone can help?

Comment: try 'addTrackViewController.delegateMixerView = mixerViewController' only.

your MixerViewController already confirming to MixerProtocol so no need to typecast.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: compiler send me this:  Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, maybe I do something wrong in the protocol to say that...

Comment: hooo and many thank's! for the answer! @Deepak

Comment: so you already got your solution?
Enjoy

Comment: well,, I check it and see what happend, if I can't found a solution I put more code... thank you for the help!

Comment: Same Issue, Already I check the protocolos line by line but nothing, and check maybe this is the problem?? create the reference??  let mixerViewController = MixerViewController( )  <- maybe this create a WHOLE or NEW VIEW.. just maybe... what do you think @Deepak?